# Loading an Array from another Array

Tags: java

IT doesn't seem to work properly

'

```
   public class junk {

public static void main(String[] args){


int[] Arr = {1,0,1,1,0,1,0};
int[] newArr = null; 

  for(int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++){

 if(isPowerOfTwo(i)) {
     newArr[i] = 9;
  }
   else{
   newArr[i] = Arr[i];

   }
}
  for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
   System.out.print(newArr[i] + ", ");
}
}




private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int i) {
    if (i <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("number: " + i);
    }
    if ((i & -i) == i) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

'

an Array 10011010 of this, and now I want this  9 9 1 9 0 0 1 9 1 0 1 0

So the power of 2 indices should be filled with 9's am i getting this right?

How would I load that data of bits in to any array or Arraylist with a loop and also with certain indices to be 9... want the 1st,2nd, 4th and 8th indices...

_ _ 1 _ 0 0 1 _ 1 0 1 0

Comment: remember that arrays are indexed from 0 to length - 1, so you may not want to check if i is a power of two.

Comment: In your loop, you're redeclaring `newArr` every iteration.  The last iteration in which the else condition was reached is the only one that sticks.  Well, it *would*, if it compiled.

Comment: I just read added the code, i get an error

Comment: Aren't you getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to access `newArr[i]`?  You only do `newArr = null`, which can't be indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in your `isPowerOfTwo()` method

- `i <= 0` for this you are throwing exception and you want to place Nine at 0th index.

Secondly you haven't initialized Array.

```
int[] newArr = new int[10];
```

Otherwise it will throw `NULLPointerException`

> want the 1st,2nd, 4th and 8th indices...

Try following condition in your `isPowerOfTwo()` method.

```
if (i == 1) {
    return true;
}
else if (i%2==0 && i%3!=0) {
    return true;
}
```

---

For Array

```
int[] Arr = {1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
```

it will give you.

```
1,9,9,1,9,1,0,1,9,1
  ^ ^   ^       ^
  1 2   4       8
```

Comment: I still can't get it right :/

if(i == 1 || i == 0) {
      return true;
  }
  else if (i%2==0 && i%3!=0) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;

Comment: Not this `if(i == 1 || i == 0)` only `if(i == 1)` as you want 9 at index 1.

Comment: hmmm not it's this 1, 9, 9, 1, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,

Comment: Solved : if (isPowerOfTwo(i+1)== true) 
Just needed to add 1

Comment: No it will not solve. you will get 9 at 1 3 5 ...but not 1 2 4.Let me remind you array index starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: if (isPowerOfTwo(i+1)== true) It has to be added + 1... that was getting mixed upp

Comment: Thats what I am trying to explain you as you stated in question you want 9 at 1 2 4 8... but you are putting it at 0th place in array.Please just add my condition to your method and you will get the solution.

Comment: Finally!! Greate Glad to help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Do not use an array. Arrays when defined must have a constant length and so if you are adding new entries into an array it is better to use an Arraylist as you can change the length of an Arraylist when adding new elements rather than an array which has a fixed length.

```
List<int[]> newArr = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

In place of using a `for` loop I think a `do while` loop would work better in this situation. If you selectively need 1st, 2nd, 4th and 8th indicies to contain 9 the following should work.

```
index = 0;
do {
    if (index == 0) {
        newArr.add(9);
        newArr.add(9);
    } else if (index == 1 || index == 4) {
        newArr.add(9);
    }
    newArr.add(Arr[index]);
    index = index + 1;
while (index < Arr.length);
```

I'm happy to work around this solution to fit your needs. I hope some part of this has helped.

Comment: i'd prefer if we use the PowerofTwo method to validate whether it should be place a 9. I need it to work with my program

Comment: Then rather than implementing the use of the two if commands you could just use if (PowerofTwo(Arr[index])). That may just as equally work? The main problem I think you had was dealing with the length of the array and the use of an ArrayList should overcome that.